I already have the plugin GLPI Inventory on my GLPI 10.0.12 and the problem is that I can't join it from another machine or my own machine
I'm having trouble connecting to my GLPI server for inventory from my virtual machine. Here is the error message generated by GLPI:
root@assane-VirtualBox:~# glpi-agent [info] target server0: server http://10.234.80.120/glpi/ [info] sending prolog request to server0 [error] [http clie
I tried to see if it's not a network issue, then I checked the permissions.

Did you enable the Inventory feature?
Administration > Inventory > Enable inventory.
It is disabled by default.
On recent versions, you will get a clear message indicating this, but it used to be a bit cryptic.
